# .rdlc Report iif do something only once

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc, iif

In an .rdlc expression i want to set a value to true if a field has a value i searched for. Otherwise it should just leave the value at the state/value that it is.
For now i am working with this expression:

```
   =iif(Fields!TerminalNr.Value = 2, false, true)
```

If the highest Terminal Number that was found is 2, than this works fine. But if it is higher the value is overwritten to true again and i cant see if 2 was in the Dataset or not.
I just want it to be set at false once it found it and then never change it again.

Hope my probelm is clear, otherwise just ask.

Thanks in advance,

InTrust

Comment: No, it's not really clear at all. Is the expression in the group footer somewhere? You should also provide some sample data you are working with and more info about the report design.

Comment: The Expression is used in a Tablix "Hidden" Property. I have 10 Tablix on the Report Page that all have this Expression in the "Hidden" property.
The Tablix should only be shown if the TerminalNr that its bound to is in the Dataset i am retrieving.
If the Terminal Number 1-4 are present, only Tablix 4 will be shown because of this Problem.